# Serving a page of a pdf on a webpage

Tags: java, pdf, google-drive-api

I've made an application that returns a pdf to a browser. It loads the pdf on a certain page that has to be visable to the user. This is working fine but loading the pdf takes a while.

To do this I give the user an object tag with data a url to google drive. When the user clicks a button the pdf starts downloading and gets displayed.

Since most of the time only 1 page is important to the user I would like to have an option to serve the pdf as a smaller file.

**Are there any libraries to load only 1 or x pages of a pdf? The main reason would be to reduce bandwidth usage.**

Maybe a google script to split the pdf and serve that as a smaller file,...

I know google has a standard docsviewer but it has many limitations. (no rotation,...) I prefer to user the adobe plugin.

Update:

I've found a project wich covers conversion in appengine.

https://github.com/lookfirst/convert

I'll check if it supports big pdf's and if it can convert pdfs from drive to images for each page. And if this is possible at real time.
I hope converting + downloading image takes less time then downloading the entire file.

Comment: There are multiple libraries allowing you to extract a single page from a document. Is your application subject to any restrictions concerning libraries or resources used?

Comment: Well if I can run it at a google I would not have to download it to my webserver. Maybe google app engine or app script. I've used pdfbox maybe I can try something with that.

Answer (score 0):

One solution for a smaller output using the Drive SDK is to convert the PDF to a Google Doc, then export as HTML.

Otherwise see the comment from @mkl.

Comment: Hmmm Is it possible to convert big pdfs to google doc? I know it's not possible to open them with drive.

Comment: Depends how big "big" is for you. Most reasonable PDFs are fine, I have a 20Mb one here I just opened.

Comment: Hmmm sometimes the pdf's I have are 28Mb or bigger,it's the main reason I wan't to send a single page :D